# How can you check date year in JavaScript for each row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I loop through the following rows in JavaScript and jQuery and

1. Check if Code == 1 and
2. Check if Date Year is only 2019 (ignore the DD-MM)?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th> 
    <th>Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>03-04-1956</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>04-05-2000</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>01-01-1990</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What you tried so far? `js` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer my solution:

```js
function checkit() {
  var table=document.getElementById("datatable");
  var rows=table.rows;
  for (var i=0; i<rows.length;i++) {
    row=rows[i];
    var dateCell=row.cells[1];
    var codeCell=row.cells[2];

    var codeData=codeCell.textContent;
    if (codeData == "1") {
      yearData=dateCell.textContent.split("-")[2];
      if (yearData==1990) {
        console.log('Hello');
        row.style="background-color: coral;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="datatable">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th> 
    <th>Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>03-04-1956</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>04-05-2000</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>01-01-1990</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="checkit()">Do Checking</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each *tr* element to check the specific *td* element's text inside:

```js
$('tr:not(":first")').each(function(){
   //get and check year
   var year = new Date($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text()).getFullYear();
   if(year == 2019)
     console.log('Year is 2019');
   else console.log('Year is not 2019');
   //get and check code
   var code = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
   if(code == "1")
     console.log('Code is 1');
   else console.log('Code is not 1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th> 
    <th>Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>03-04-1956</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>04-05-2000</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>01-01-1990</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a thead/tbody
2. Use querySelectorAll and forEach
3. Use split
4. Use classList.toggle

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('#tbl tbody tr')].forEach(row => {
  const cells = row.querySelectorAll("td");
  row.classList.toggle('dateOk',
    cells[1].textContent.split("-")[2] === "2019" &&
    cells[2].textContent === "1"
  )
})
```

```css
.dateOk {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>03-04-1956</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>04-05-2019</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>01-01-1990</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run on all `tr` and ignore the headers (first `tr`):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(:first-child)').forEach(tr => {
    const year = new Date(tr.cells[1].innerText).getFullYear();
    const code = tr.cells[2].innerText;
        if(year == 2019 && code == 1){
            tr.style.color = 'blue';
        }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th> 
    <th>Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>03-04-1956</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>04-05-2019</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>01-01-1990</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```